# convert many-to-many with extra field to regular join table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the 3 entities: Formula, Color and FormulaColor(which is basically a join table but with an extra percentage column).

How would I convert that to using just regular join table(s)?

If it's important, the percentage is just telling what percentage a given color has for a given formula.

**EDIT**

I wasn't clear enough. I want to change the structure of my DB so that the percentage is not stored in the FormulaColor table. How would I do this but still keep the functionality of keep track of a percentage of a color for a certain formula?

**ANOTHER EDIT, SCHEMA**

This should be all the related schema necessary.

### Color

id

### Formula

id

### FormulaCOlor

color_id

formula_id

percentage

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: give schema of your tables and tell us what is relation between all the tables

Answer (score 0):

Ss you did not provided enough details about the tables I think that you need something like this:

```
Select * 
from formula f
foin formulacolor fc on f.id_formula = fc.id_formula
join colori c on c.id_colori = fc.id_colori
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Sorry, not what I was looking for. I revised my question so hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: i see, however I don't understand why I got -1 as long time as you did not had enough details :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need

```
select * from formulaColor fc
 Inner join formula f on fc.formula_id = f.id
 Inner join Color c on fc.Color_id = c.id
```

Comment: I'm NOT trying to select any data or get any specific sql. I want to know how I would structure my db to move the percentage out of the formulacolor table!

Comment: @user45763 why you dont want percentage column in formulaColor table?

Comment: It is convenient for having a simple DB structure and less joins etc but it makes my development more of a pain especially when it comes to creating fake data fixtures.

Comment: @user45763 Cant you move percentage column to formula table and just join formula and color table with each other with id. So in that case you dont need formulacolor table

Comment: No. This is M:N between Color and Formula. A formula may require a certain percentage of color A while another formula may require a different percentage of color A.

Comment: @user45763 is it possible to put everything in just one table?